# Setting an instance variable of a child class that extends an abstract class

Tags: java, swing, polymorphism, abstract, shapes

I have a class called `Shape` that is abstract, and a class named `Circle` that extends Shape

```
Shape shapeCircle = new Circle();
```

I can set and get colors of shapeCircle fine because the color getters and setters are in Shape , but the dimensions of Circle is only for the Circle class (radius).

If Circle class has an instance variable `private int radius` and a method called `getRadius()`, how can I get/set the radius of `shapeCircle`? I tried `shapeCircle.getRadius();`, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Shape shapeCircle = new Circle();
```

Here the reference is of Shape and shape class doesn't defines radius variable.So you cannot use `shapeCircle.getRadius();`

To invoke get/set radious method type cast the shapecircle variable like this

```
Circle shapeCircle = (Circle)shapeCircle;
```

Now you can invoke the get/set radious methods. Please note that typecasting code should be in some different method to benefit using polymorphism.

EDIT:

You should design your abstract classes or interfaces to be having all important/common  operations/methods which will help you in writing polymorphic code. For example: Radius field is specific to a Circle class.But consider you eventually want to calculate the area. So you should define CalculateArea() method in your abstract class and let every shape implement this method.This way, you achieve polymorphism.

```
Shape ShapeCicle = new Circle(Radius);
Float area = ShapeCircle.area();
```

Point is don't confine yourself with the radius example.Try to define classes in a way so that you can benefit from polymorphism.

Comment: I would like to benefit from polymorphism, but I can't grasp the point of abstract methods if I can just make an instance of the Circle class and its methods directly

Comment: ((Circle)shapeCircle).setRadius(230); works, don't know if it is polymorphism

Comment: I have updated my answer with some comments. Please check @Dog

Answer (score 3):

> Only methods of Shape are accessible with object shapeCircle.
>   shapeCircle is type Shape, methods in Circle are not visible.

By using this,

```
 Circle shapeCircle = new Circle();
```

you can call both method of Circle and Shape. The above case is take advantage of only **Inheritance**.

**Edit**

But if you add `public abstract int getDimension();` in `Shape` class and `Circle` class implements `getDimension()` method

```
@Override
    public int getDimension() {
        return radius;
    }
```

All classes that extends `Shape` needs to implements `getDimension()` method. But each subclass has its own dimension.

You can use

```
    Shape shapeCircle = new Circle();
    shapeCircle.getDimension();
```

This takes advantage of both **polymorphism and abstract class**.

Comment: Thanks, I can access the methods now, but I don't understand the ppoint of Shape abstract class if I declare it this way.

Comment: I added more explanation. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `instanceof` keyword to check for the original type here . If the type is `Circle`, then you can type cast and call the `getRadius` method. Something like

```
if (shapeCircle instanceof Circle) {
 Circle circle = (Circle)shapeCircle;
 int radius = circle.getRadius();
}
```

That should do.

Answer (score 0):

'Shape is not Circle' = Circle methods not available for Shape.